# .text area of memory layout

Tags: c, memory, layout

My Question is related to the memory layout in embedded system

I learned that when we flash(or burn) a executable file it sits either in ROM or FLASH depending on the hardware we use.

But i also learned from the memory layout of a c-program that program segment contains the .text area ( i.e compiled code)

My question is :
1) Is it the same code what we burn in flash/ROM sits in RAM(as depicted in .text area of program code) 
2) Two copies are created one in flash/ROM and RAM ??

Comment: Your question is not really related to C language. If you execute your binary code from ROM/Flash or from RAM depends on your hardware. There is some Flash that can be used with direct memory acces, some cannot. In the latter case the code needs to be copied to RAM. Also the existence of a `.text` segment is not C standard. I used some C compiler that named the segments following a different scheme. The segment holding code was named `CODE` instead of `.text`. Therefore you should closely read documentation for your architecture and your compiler tool chain.

Comment: Hi Gerhardh...  i would like to reiterate my question .. what does the .text area of RAM consist actually ? does it has the replica of code what we burn in RAM/FLASH .. what is the use of .text area ?

Comment: You cannot execute any code directly from ROM. It will be terribly slow and addresses won't make sense on ROM. SO a copy of the code is loaded in the RAM in the `.text` section and the execution happens there.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it has an almost replica of the code on the ROM. Some times due to relocation or in case it is compressed and kept on the ROM, the code might be changed by the loader.

Comment: Btw the `.text` section also is there in the binary file (the one on ROM).

Comment: Which part of "not C related" and "it depends on your hardware" is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

1) Depending on your hardware, the .text (and other segments) may be accessible directly in flash/ROM, or (in the case of serial flash), it may need to be copied into RAM to be executable.

2) The version in flash/ROM is the only version, UNTIL execution starts.  Then (depending on the answers in 1), some start up code MAY copy the ROM into RAM to execute it, OR it may execute directly from the flash/ROM. Once executing, the C start up code MAY copy (or initialise) some of the non-code segments into RAM (e.g. .data, .bss etc).

Older, slower processors, may execute from ROM (think 8086/6502 era), whereas more modern processors (Pentium+ era, FPGA etc) would run incredibly slowly if executing from flash, so they will copy the executable into RAM (and even then, the currently executing code will be cached into the processor itself, so there may be a 3rd copy of the code).